# Getting preg_replace(): Parameter mismatch, pattern is a string while replacement is an array while doing update query in Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a JSON format like below,

```
 {"projectId":"1","projectName":"My Project","total_project_cost":2200000,"total":2400000,"totalPercentFee":7,"adderArray":[{"name":"Adder 1","value":"100000","firmApercentage":"","firmBpercentage":""},{"name":"Adder 2","value":"100000","firmApercentage":"","firmBpercentage":""}]
```

In this to insert adderArray i have user laravel $cast.

So my model is looking like this

```
protected $table = 'projects_percent_fee_management';

protected $casts = [
    'adder_data' => 'array',
    'project_breakdown' => 'array',
];

protected $fillable = ['project_id','company_id','total_project_cost','adder_data','total','total_percent_fee','project_breakdown','total_budget'];
```

Insert is working well and it insert the adderArray data properly in adder_data field.

But while update it gives preg_replace(): Parameter mismatch, pattern is a string while replacement is an array error and in field it updates "Array".

Answer (score 0):

I think while updating, you are trying to pass the parameters whose corresponding columns are not present in the table (database / model).

To make this work, use `$fillable` variable inside Model. e.g.:

```
$fillable = ['column_1', 'column_2', 'column_3', 'column_4',..., 'column_n'];
```

By adding `$fillable` inside your model the update query will take only those parameters in updating which are defined in `$fillable` array.

Hope it helps you. For more detailed info about Mass Assignment in Laravel - [see this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#mass-assignment)